# Store Cart not showing items

Tags: expresso-store, shopping-cart

I am working the store default templates into my custom layout. I am using the {exp:store:cart} tag to display totals in my site's header, however it is not displaying any data.  If I browse to the example templates it still shows the items in the cart.

I am perplexed to why this is not working, wondering if its a server configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it has to do with sessions or cookies.  This site is still in development and the sites url is an IP address.  The page the cart was NOT working on I accessed via a subdomain that pointed to the IP.  This meant the cookie/session was under a different site.

TLDR - Make sure your sites domain is the same for all functions of Expresso-Store to work.